# How to remove specifc hash_value from array of hash value using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, hash

I have `hash_arr = [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]`

In  object value is like this `hash_arr[0] = Object {3: "[3, 1, 2]"}`

Now I want to remove value from the array if it is present with loop

I did code like below mentioned.

```
$("#question_check").change(function() {
  $('.question_checkbox').each(function(){
    var val = e.val();
      var data_lo = e.attr('data-lo');
      if(e.is(':checked')){
        new_hash = {};
        new_hash[val] = data_lo;
        if(checked_box_hash.includes(new_hash)){
          checked_box_hash;
        }else{
          checked_box_hash.push(new_hash);
        }
      }
      else{
        if(checked_box_hash.includes(new_hash)){
          var idx = checked_box_hash.indexOf(new_hash);
          checked_box_hash.splice( $.inArray(new_hash,checked_box_hash) ,1 );
        }else{
          checked_box_hash;
        }
      }
  });
});
```

It is only worked for first value all others will remain same.

Please help if you know the solution.

Comment: Your array is a string try to use `JSON.parse` and after you splice call `JSON.stringify`. or if you want to keep array use `var data_lo = JSON.parse(e.attr('data-lo'));`

Comment: i want data like same as in object i can not modify.